# Update upstream nuget packages in Azure Devops artifact to latest version

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

We have configured Artifact feeds for all package source like nuget and powershell gallary. Because of some billing issue we have deleted latest versions of NuGet packages from Feed and even from Recycle Bin. Now we can't restore all packages latest versions. We also changed retention policy to maximum 1 version per packagae and 1 days to keep recently downloaded packages.

Now our build pipelines and local Visual Studio builds are started failing. How can we configure Custom Feed to use latest version of Nuget packages from upstream sources?
We have modified retention policy to 10 number of versions per package but still it says latest upstream version is deleted from feed.
How can we refresh Feed with latest packages versions?

Comment: It’s worth trying following rest call: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifactspackagetypes/nuget/update-package-versions?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0